# Using @EnableIntegration when multiple @Configuration classes are present

Tags: spring-integration

In Spring Integration, all the examples I see show `@Configuration` classes also annotated with `@EnableIntegration`.

The thing is, I am building some pretty complicated flows, and I don't like the idea of having one massive `@Configuration` file. I prefer to break Java projects down into packages by feature, and allow each feature to have its own `@Configuration` class (separation of concerns, etc.). So I'd like to do the same thing with each of my individual flows.

Do I:

- Add `@EnabledIntegration`/`@EnabledIntegrationManagement` to **all** my `@Configuration` classes?; or
- Only add `@EnabledIntegration`/`@EnabledIntegrationManagement` to only *one* of my `@Configuration` classes (and if so, does it matter which one?); or
- Add `@EnabledIntegration`/`@EnabledIntegrationManagement` to my `@SpringBootApplication` main class?; or
- Something else?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare it only once per application context, as any other `@Enable…` in Spring. On any of your `@Configuration` class which contributes to the application context with Spring Integration. You don’t need it with Spring Boot, though, it does declare that one for us.

Comment: Ahh nice! So with Spring Boot: no need to explicitly annotate _anything_ with either `@EnableIntegration` or `@EnableIntegrationManagement`?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to declare those manually. Spring Boot even takes care for us about `@IntegrationComponentScan`.